# Can't switch to NVIDIA card in GNOME after installing Weston and/or changing Modeset

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, 17.10

I'm on Artful and I have an NVIDIA 940MX GPU. I've been happily switching between my nvidia and intel graphics constantly, but now it won't work.

`prime-select` prints regular output as if it worked, but it doesn't seem to actually change anything.

However, at my gdm login screen, I still get separate "Ubuntu" and "Ubuntu on Xorg" options (typically Xorg becomes implied when NVIDIA is active). The Xorg option does not work, it just exits back to gdm. The Wayland option actually logs in, *but*:

- `nvidia-settings` reports "Unable to find display on any available system"
- `glxinfo` reports that I am on my Intel card

I have done two things that may have caused this:

- Installed `weston`, and thus XWayland
- In `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf`, I set `modeset=1`. When I realized that trying to switch to my Intel card after doing this results in an infinite loop of dmesg errors and renders my device useless, I booted into Recovery Mode, set it back to `modeset=0`, and ran `prime-select nvidia` from there just to be safe. I then rebooted.

I'm pretty sure the second one caused the issue, but I'm not certain, and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been caused by Problem no. 2, as I expected.

The solution was:

1. Remove the modeset line entirely (and update initramfs, of course)
2. Prime-select intel
3. Prime-select nvidia again
4. Reboot